# Sliding columns and rows in a 2D List

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a simple solitaire game in which the goal is to shift rows and columns of varying colors until they form a specific pattern. I am trying to represent the configuration of my game board using a 2d list:

```
board = [['W', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
         ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
         ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
         ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
```

Let's suppose that we have the following goal board:

```
goal = [['W', 'B', 'B', 'W'],
        ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
        ['W', 'W', 'B', 'B'],
        ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
```

For a given move you may only shift the elements of one column up or down, or one row right or left. Elements that fall off the end of the board are cycled back to the opposite side of the column or row being shifted. How might I implement functions to achieve this functionality? The implementation for the shifting of elements along a row seems fairly straightforward to me, for example:

```
def shift_left(board, row_num, num_tiles):
    for i in range(0, num_tiles):
        elem = board.pop(0)
        board.append(elem)
```

Am I on the right track? How might I approach implementing the functions for shifting elements along a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can go about this

```
from copy import deepcopy

def shift(board, ix, direction):
    if direction is 'up':
        return shift_col(board, ix, direction)
    if direction is 'down':
        return shift_col(board, ix, direction)
    if direction is 'left':
        return shift_row(board, ix, direction)
    if direction is 'right':
        return shift_row(board, ix, direction)

def shift_col(board, col_ix, direction):
    temp = [row[col_ix] for row in board]

    if direction is 'up':
        temp = temp[1:len(temp)] + [temp[0]]
    if direction is 'down': 
        temp = [temp[-1]] + temp[0:-1]

    for ix, i in enumerate(board):
        i[col_ix] = temp[ix]
    return board

def shift_row(board, row_ix, direction):
    if direction is 'right':
        temp = [board[row_ix][-1]] + board[row_ix][0:-1]
    if direction is 'left':
        temp = board[row_ix][1:len(board[row_ix])] + [board[row_ix][0]]
    board[row_ix] = temp
    return board
```

Then we can use this in the following way

```
board = [['W', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
         ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
         ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
         ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]

# Shifts the board for a row or column index
# in the specified direction.
# up/down: ix is for columns
# left/right: ix is for rows
board = shift(deepcopy(board), 2, 'down')
for i in board:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Oh great, an answer that spoon-feeds code without letting OP at all think for themselves. There's no more need to develop their own code, they can just copy paste yours and everything is hunky-dory. Your code really explains nothing of what it does.

Comment: A little example can help someone get started or learn about new ways of doing things that they would not otherwise have been exposed to. Two different pedagogical methods. In the long term, your method is arguably better, however in the short term, learning by example provides for a faster climb up the learning curve. A good balance of both is probably best. Furthermore, points are awarded based on the OP's perceived notion of the best answer (what helps him most). Thus, for the OP and me it is a win/win game. Don't hate the player, hate the game.

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your board and then reuse routines previously defined. Here's how you'd do this for `shift_down`.

```
def transpose(lst):
    return list(map(list, zip(*lst)))

def shift_down(board, row_num, num_tiles):
    board = transpose(board)
    shift_left(board)
    board = transpose(board)
```

A similar process follows for `shift_right` and `shift_up`.